# How can I get junit tearDown method run if an exception is thown on startup?

Tags: selenium, junit

I'm running selenium tests through junit.
In my system the setUp method of our AbstractSeleniumTestCase class sets up the selenium web driver and firefox profile, and the tearDown method logs out of the system and closes selenium.

Some tests will override the setUp and tearDown methods to do custom test setUp and tearDown.

The problem I'm having is that if an error accrues in the startUp method of a test (Like an unexpected popup or an selenium exception) then the web browser is never closed and the test specific tearDown operations are never done.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `try` block in the `setUp()` method to run `tearDown()` after encountering an error, and move the "meat" of the test setup into another method:

```java
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    try {
        mySetUp();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tearDown();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Then, in your subclasses, override `mySetUp()` instead of `setUp()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a [TestWatcher](http://junit.czweb.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) and override finished method that, according to docs:

> Invoked when a test method finishes (whether passing or failing)

I have not used JUnit for some time now, but as much as I remember, rules were applied before `@Before`.

Also you can init the driver in overriding starting method and take any relevant action by overriding the failed method etc. By that way it is possible to get rid of repetitive stuff on `@Before` and `@After`.  Check the docs for specifics.

Then you can annotate your test classes with either `@Rule` or `@ClassRule`, google to understand which better suits your needs. For your any possible specific needs, it is also possible to create a [rule chain](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.11/org/junit/rules/RuleChain.html).